# C#: How to connect to Active Directory with SSL enabled?

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory

The project I am working on will integrate with the customers Active Directory in order to authenticate users. I have been trying to write some code that will retrieve a users password and I understand that Active Directory will only expose the relevant properties over a SSL connection on port 636.

The following code connects programmatically without using SSL but then I can't see the password properties:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://<IP>/CN=LDAP Test,CN=Users,DC=customer,DC=com");
    entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
    entry.Username = "CN=LDAP Test,CN=Users,DC=customer,DC=com";
    entry.Password = "<password>";
    if (entry != null)
    {
        foreach (Object propName in entry.Properties.PropertyNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((String)propName);
        }
    }
}
```

When I change the code to use SSL I get an exception stating ;Unknown error (0x80005000)'.

I have enabled SSL on the server hosting Active Directory, installed a Microsoft CA on the same server and obtained a certificate from the CA.

I can connect to the Active Directory over SSL using Apache Directory Studio but that does not show the password properties.

The following code shows what I have been trying to use to connect using SSL:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAPS://<IP>:636/CN=LDAP Test,CN=Users,DC=customer,DC=com");
    entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
    entry.Username = "CN=LDAP Test,CN=Users,DC=customer,DC=com";
    entry.Password = "<password>";
    if (entry != null)
    {
        foreach (Object propName in entry.Properties.PropertyNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((String)propName);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where to go with this and some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287100/setting-up-ssl-in-active-directory-how-to/291826

Comment: The ADAM FAQ is here: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/ADAMfaq.mspx#EOD

Comment: The title for this question is misleading, it should be something like, "How can I retrieve a user's password from Active Directory?"  It has nothing to do with "connect to Active Directory with SSL enabled?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been trying to write some code
>   that will retrieve a users password...

This is unrelated to your SSL problem, but I don't think retrieving a user's password from Active Directory is possible. It only stores a hash and that's why you aren't receiving any kind of "password" property when querying the user's properties.

**Updated Answer**

After reading your comment, it appears you're looking for the unicodePwd attribute which contains the security hash. According to the [MSDN information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248%28PROT.10%29.aspx), writing to that attribute requires the special SSL connection but you still won't be able to read it because it's a write-only attribute.

Specifically from MSDN:

> The  unicodePwd  attribute is never returned by an LDAP search.

Here's also a forum post that I found that seems to say the same thing:

> The users' password is stored in the
>   Active Directory on a user object in
>   the unicodePwd attribute. This
>   attribute can be written under
>   restricted conditions, but it cannot
>   be read due to security reasons.
>   ([Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/63e3cf2d-f186-418e-bc85-58bdc1861aae))

Comment: It's the hash that I'm after. I admit my post could have been clearer about that. The intent is to compare or authorise a hash received from another system with the hash stored in Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the server's certificate and root certificate to your local store. The easiest way to do this is to use IE to connect to https://your.domain.contoller:636. Then click through all the certificate screens and add them to your store.